# How I can set min-width for mobile and don't change viewport on Bootstrap3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap and I set:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    body {
        min-width:500px;
    }
}
```

And when I login with my phone I have viewport less then window width, like that:

[image: What i have]

I need to set viewport same as window width. In bootstrap I have header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And bootstrap says that I can't delete that. How can I edit my code to have viewport on mobile same as window width?

Comment: I don't see any reason why your viewport could be less than window width. It's probably an issue with some of your CSS. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: As I can see, you set body width 500px min... so, if your mobiles has  e.g. 320px, the rest of the content will be out of your view. 
Why did you set width to body? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @AlbertoRubio I need increase width of site on all mobile phones. When I log in 320px width phone and tap to decrease scale (after that i have full width scale) my site on phone look perfect, beter than 320px width. So I need to scale view on mobile phone to full-width by default

Comment: @TJ done, try to run this on mobile 320px(emulate on chrome, ets) and u weel see the scrol bar and not full width view by default http://embed.plnkr.co/fHufomNU40OvojeStvRj/

Comment: @Maelnor reading the comments above, I don't really understand what you're trying to do. So you have `500px` content on a `320px` screen so maybe you want to set `initial-scale=1` to something smaller? But it seems wrong. You should probably write media queries to handle the resolution than doing such things. BTW I can't really think of anyone viewing websites on a `320px` wide screen in 2016 ...

Comment: @TJ Ok, I try to explain. Look, i have mobile phone LG g4 (2k resolution on screen) and when i log in to site (in link abowe) i have a horizontal scroll bar, and amazing big scale. Why I with so big phone resolution have so small viewport by default? I need to see full width screen by default on my phone. How i can did it?

Comment: @Maelnor Your mobiles resolution and CSS `px` are different, it is not considered as 2000px in CSS. You should design the site responsively so that content doesn't overflow in smaller screens usng media queries, bootstrap responsive classes etc.

Comment: @TJ i don't have any problems with content owerflow, my content is pretty awesome contain in mobile. I need simply increase site width on mobile. Look, now i have this: http://i.piccy.info/i9/9b73fc750335de628681a870d043bb2d/1463124854/150268/1033513/2.jpg and when i set min width 500px i have that: http://i.piccy.info/i9/3fa86ebafd96ffafe4cb95381cd4149d/1463124786/216178/1033513/Screenshot_2016_05_13_10_24_39.jpg and second picture is more pretty that first. But in second variant i have scroll by default :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your issue is related to the view port. But in case if it is, you can try the following view port code.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />`

Comment: That don't help, nothing changes

Comment: pls try adding width:100% before your, 'min-width:500px;'.

Answer (score 0):

Its just because you have set **min-width** property to **body** element.

Try to use **.container** class from bootstrap it will solve your problem.

If you just wanted to use body element then go for this one...

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    body {
        width:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your content should be at least 500px wide, set min-width on your body.

```
body {
   min-width: 500px;
}
```

If you want it to start zoomed out (as if viewport is 500px wide), use shrink-to-fit:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=yes">
```